# Retrieve last sent messages from xmpp servers after disconnect

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I have created an IM app that uses asmack to connect to various xmpp protocols such as google talk and facebook.

Occasionally some messages are lost in transit (both sent and received messages) when switching between Wifi/Data or when you lose signal altogether. Is there any way to retrieve the last received messages for that particular protocol when the app manages to reconnect? I find myself having to constantly check the default messaging app to see if any messages came through while I was disconnected.

Also, how about a way to get obtain delivery confirmation upon sending a message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a server that supports [XEP-0136: Message Archiving](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) or [XEP-0313: Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html), you'll be able to obtain all messages previously sent.

However, neither Google Talk nor Facebook Chat implements these, and afaik they have no alternative XMPP API for it either.